# What is the difference between "lea eax, [ebx + eax]" and "add eax, ebx" in x86-32 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

GCC made me some assembly code, and inside theres this statement:

```
lea eax, [ebx+eax]
```

(Intel Syntax)
Just curious, what would the difference between that, and:

```
add eax, ebx
```

Be?

eax, and ebx contains return values from functions :)

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax 
call CALC1
mov ebx, eax.
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
call CALC2
lea eax, [ebx+eax]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEA or ADD instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323027/lea-or-add-instruction)

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功: Unfortunately the answers to that question aren't very accurate.  The highest voted / accepted answer claims that `lea` runs on the AGU.  In-order Atom works that way, (and needs its inputs ready earlier but produces outputs earlier in the pipeline, too, or something like that), but out-of-order CPUs including Silvermont aren't like that.  I guess I should just answer that question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the info. I recommend that you answer that question if none of the answers is correct, comment on wrong answers (looks like you did already), and comment on question in the hope that OP will change the accept (unlikely). I don't think it should affect the duplicate direction in this case: that one just has way more upvotes. This is also a great opportunity for you to get rep due to the "create justice" effect :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the result into another register than EAX, such as `lea edx, eax + ebx`. `add` cannot do it.

`lea` can also have an additional third operand such as `lea eax, ebp + esi + 12` which makes it a handier alternative to `add` instruction.

You can also combine certain (word-sized) multiplication operations with it, such as `lea eax, ebp + eax * 8`.

Not to mention that it describes the intent better :)

Answer (score 11):

One difference that immediately springs to mind is that `lea` doesn't affect the flags, whereas `add` does.

It is impossible to say without seeing the rest of the assembly code whether this is of any relevance. It could simply be an artefact of the GCC's code generator (i.e. it could in fact be producing code for a more general case or just using `lea` as a more flexible `add`.)

Answer (score 5):

In terms of the numeric result, there is no difference.

However, there is more to an instruction than the actual result that is stored in the destination register:

1. As **aix** pointed out, `lea` does not set the flags based on the result of the addition.  This is occasionally useful for instruction scheduling purposes.
2. There are also timing differences on some micro-architectures (early Atom cores); specifically, there are stalls involved in forwarding results between the arithmetic and address-generation units, and using either `add` or `lea` depending on context can eliminate these (very small) stalls.

Comment: In some older Intel processors, lea can be MUCH slower than add.  Not sure about the current crop, but suspect that's probably no longer the case.

Comment: True; in AMD's Athlon and later, it might be beneficial - it's in fact a way to eek out another parallel op since `LEA` is handled by the addressing engine not the ALUs.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, both are single-cycle operations on all current Intel processors that I am aware of (though on some processors it is possible to issue *more* `add` instructions at once).

Comment: @FrankH: `LEA` runs on the ALUs in Intel (Haswell: p1/p5 for simple, p1 only for 3-component or rip-relative.  p0 only for PII/PIII) and AMD CPUs (EX0/1 in Bulldozer-family).  I even checked P4, and it runs `LEA` on the same ALU ports as `ADD`.  Via Nano2/3000 runs `LEA` on its store-address port, though, vs. `ADD` on I1/I2 integer ALUs.  [Agner Fog's table](http://agner.org/optimize/) says LEA has "extra latency to other ports", which sounds like what Stephen said about Atom (which also runs LEA on AGU1, rather than ALU0/1).  Silvermont is like other OOO chips, though; LEA on ALUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes: right, what I wrote in the answer is only true of early Atom cores (Bonnell/Saltwell).  Silvermont is much more modern.

Comment: Yup, of course.  I wasn't criticizing your answer, just FrankH's response (and answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323027/lea-or-add-instruction).  Atom and Silvermont are very different architectures.  Fun fact, though: K8 and K10 run (complex) LEA in their AGUs.  Your point 2 helped make some sense of those notes in Agner Fog's table about taking longer to forward results between AGU and ALU.  (I haven't even read the Atom section in his microarch pdf, though, and it's probably mentioned there.)