# In x86-64, why the address of a structure sometimes be a pointer type and sometimes be a long type?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, x86-64, memory-address

I read the chapter 3 of the textbook "Computer Systems: A Programmer Perspective". Chapter 3 is about introducing instruction set architecture(ISA) of x86-64. In this chapter, there are several examples of assembly code that were compiled from C programs. In these examples, I encountered two questions which are about the address of structure.

First, suppose the starting address of integer array E and integer index i are stored in register %rdx and %rcx, respectively. The following shows an assembly-code implementation of each expression:

| Expression | Type | Value | Assembly code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | int * | X<sub>E</sub> | movl %rdx, %rax |
| E[0] | int | M[X<sub>E</sub>] | movl (%rdx), %eax |
| &E[2] | int * | X<sub>E</sub>+8 | leaq 8(%rdx), %rax |
| &E[i]-E | long | i | movq %rcx, %rax |

Why the expression `&E[i]-E` be the `long` type instead of the `int *` type? Why the value of `&E[i]-E` be `i` instead of `4i`?

Second, suppose a structure:

```
typedef union {
    struct{
        long u;
        short v;
        char w;
    }t1;
    struct{
        int a[2];
        char *p;
    }t2;
} u_type;
```

You write a series of functions of the form

```
void get(u_type *up, type *dest){
    *dest = expr;
}
```

with different access expression *expr* and with destination data type *type* set according to type associated with *expr*. Suppose in these functions that *up* and *dest* are loaded into register %rdi and %rsi, respectively.The following table is about the assembly code of the expression:

| Expression | Type | Assembly code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| up->t1.u | long | movq (%rdi), %rax \n movq %rax, (%rsi) |
| &up->t1.w | char * | addq $10, %rdi \n movq %rdi, (%rsi) |

Considering expression `&up->t1.w`, I know that we want to assign the the address of the `char w` to `dest` and the offset of the `char w` is 10 bytes of the beginning of the structure. But why the answer is to store 10 to `dest` instead of storing `10(%rdi)` to `dest`? If the answer is correct, why the type is `char *` instead of `long`?

To make it clear, why the assembly code of the expression `&up->t1.w` not like this:

```
leaq 10(%rdi), %rax
movq %rax, (%rsi)
```

Comment: For the pointer subtraction, you can refer to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238482/555045). `addq $10, %rdi` doesn't store 10 in rdi, it adds 10 to rdi.

Comment: Harry, `&E[i]-E` is subtracting two pointers.  That different is an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: About `leaq` vs `addq` there is sometimes more than one "correct" way to do the same thing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323027/lea-or-add-instruction

Answer (score 0):

It makes little or no sense at all to analyze not optimized code. If you enable the optimizations all your problems disappear magically.

```
struct s1{
    int a[2];
    char *p;
};

typedef union {
    struct{
        long u;
        short v;
        char w;
    };
    struct s1 s;
} u_type;

void get(u_type *up, char *dest)
{
    *dest = up -> w;
}

        movzbl  10(%rdi), %eax
        movb    %al, (%rsi)
        ret

void get(u_type *up, long *dest)
{
    *dest = up -> u;
}

        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        movq    %rax, (%rsi)
        ret

void get(u_type *up, struct s1 *dest)
{
    *dest = up -> s;
}

        movdqu  (%rdi), %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, (%rsi)
        ret

void get(u_type *up, int *dest)
{
    *dest = up -> s.a[1];
}

        movl    4(%rdi), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%rsi)
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xPPvTbPTq