# gcc using `lea` instead of `add`

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, addition, cpu-architecture

I wanted to remember how a compiler performs integer division by 2.
Interestingly, I found a particular behavior that I do not understand:

https://godbolt.org/z/87n3x5Gjv

```cpp
    int div2(int x)
    {
        return x / 2;
    }
```

`x86_64 gcc 13.2 -O1`

```
    div2(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 31
        lea     eax, [rax+rdi]
        sar     eax
        ret
```

I personally would have swapped `lea` with `add`, -O0 and -O2 do that, also clang does that at any level.
Does this have something to do with the flags that the `add` instruction might modify?
I would love to know why something like this might happen, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEA or ADD instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323027/lea-or-add-instruction)

Comment: There is no benefit to using `lea` here. The flags don't matter and the non-destructiveness isn't used nor any other benefit. Note that the top answer to the linked question is wrong, so be careful with that.

Comment: @DanielA.White it's useful and very interesting to know the difference between the two, but i was more interested in why gcc chooses lea in this case where the more frequent solution is add

Comment: @DanielA.White: The highest-voted / accepted answer on [LEA or ADD instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6328441) is currently wrong about execution units and about latency for modern x86.  It might have been true on in-order Atom.  Oh, according to my comment on it, it was also true on AMD K8 and K10, which surprisingly did run LEA on their AGUs, competing with load and store-address uops.  So it's not a very good duplicate; IMO we could use a fresh start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think LEA is worse here, probably the result of some heuristic gone wrong.  You could report it with the "missed optimization" keyword on GCC's bugzilla, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/
I've noticed this, too, that some compilers seem to prefer LEA for no reason even when they don't need to copy the result to a destination that wasn't either of the inputs.

---

LEA runs on fewer ports on some CPUs, such Intel before Ice Lake.  At least it's still a "simple" LEA on all modern CPUs, 2 components and no scale factor on the index.  Otherwise it could run on even fewer ports, and might have latency higher than 1 cycle.  (https://uops.info/)  (But doing the work of 2 to 4 instructions with a more complex LEA is usually still worth it, unless it's part of a loop-carried dependency chain.)

LEA does cost extra code size for the SIB byte in the addressing mode.  (opcode + ModRM + SIB for 3-byte `lea`, just opcode + ModRM for 2-byte `add eax, edi`)

Not writing FLAGS isn't useful here.  x86 CPUs handle FLAGS writes fully efficiently, even using the same physical-register-file entry for both the FLAGS and the integer result.  (Sandybridge-family definitely does this; I assume Zen and others do as well, instead of needing another whole register file and register-allocation-table or something, or needing uops to have 2 outputs.)  Some GCC devs might be unsure about this: I seem to recall a comment on a GCC bugzilla issue suggesting that not modifying FLAGS would have some advantage, like less work for the CPU not to have to rename it.  That's not the case.

When you're already writing a register destination, writing FLAGS as well has zero extra cost.  It might even allow freeing up an older physical register that was holding just a FLAGS result but not also the current value of any integer reg.